# Room get the next Row(Item) in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Hi I am new to the Android room library, Ok I have a working program that display Notes and uses the Android Room components.
I am not searching for an Exact source code any suggestion or general guidance is fine with regards to this.

So I have a Class Note, A DAO class, A repository class, the database class, the ViewModel, an Adapter for a list view. The interface has a main activity and two fragments, the fist fragment displays list of notes and in EditNote Fragment where we are displaying just one note in details. This is correct [with regards to the google documentation.](http://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components)

Everything is good and when I click an element of the list I get the EditNote 
 Fragment.

All the code is exactly as shown in [this tutorial](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/room-viewmodel-livedata-recyclerview-mvvm/part-10-listadapter)

Now I want to add a Navigation button next in the EditNote Fragment.

- In the detail Fragment we get the Note class from the construcor and I am setting some vars  in the oncreatedview event by overriding it and getting the ViewModel to set up the observer that will trigger the OnChange.

From what I read I need to change the current note (selected Row in the table) to trigger this OnChange event to display the next note (next row)
So : if we click on the next button we display the next Note row element, and by clicking on previous we display the previous note element.

- **Do I have to rewrite everything to the Dao Level with a query where I input the current note ID to get the next Note ? (can i do it using SQL?)**
- **Does this room component system have an option to get the current row and change it?**
  [image]

Comment: you can get the whole list here when you are clicking on a particular note for editing , and by using that list you can show next and previous note here in edit fragment

Comment: Hi Sandeep dhiman , Thanks for the answer . So  you  get the list  you can make a private <List<Note>> and pass it to the fragment on create that should work. I am thinking to override the Dao to get the next row from the current row id and change the repo, viewmodel which is a totally diffrent way of solving this . Thanks again for this suggestion which should work, the only bad thing is thatit is not the best for large lists (if ur passing that to fragment constructor) .

Comment: If you already have a list then making asynchronous call each time a next or previous is pressed is not a good practice.You can get next or previous note and can update the same using your viewmodel.

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman Yeah that is what I am trying to do

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman  Thinking of adding this in Dao,    @Query("SELECT * FROM Note_table WHERE id LIKE :id ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1")
    public Note getNextNote(String id);

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman I need to make this work in Async , so now I get this error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman Thats the Idea might work Still in progress

Comment: still you are not getting me

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman yeah I made a huge mistake and I am correcting it now lol